# How to specify Apache Camel data format when using bean-integration in spring environment?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

How to indicate that my endpoint (or, ideally, globally: all endpoints) require converting POJOs to `application/json` format before sending?

Say, i have a REST controller, which injects endpoint to rabbitmq exchange and i want objects i send via this exchange to be serialized into json, somehow like this:

```
@RestController
public class Partners {
    @EndpointInject(uri = "rabbitmq:core/partners/create")
    private ProducerTemplate partnersCreate;

    @RequestMapping("/partners/create")
    public Partner create(Partner partner) {

        return partnersCreate.requestBody(partner, Partner.class);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that camel apparently have no idea what to do with a POJO:

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.example.core.client.model.Partner to the required type: byte[] with value com.example.core.client.model.Partner@29069cf5
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:206) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQMessagePublisher.publish(RabbitMQMessagePublisher.java:86) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint.publishExchangeToChannel(RabbitMQEndpoint.java:216) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer$2.doWithChannel(RabbitMQProducer.java:289) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer$2.doWithChannel(RabbitMQProducer.java:286) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.execute(RabbitMQProducer.java:90) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.basicPublish(RabbitMQProducer.java:286) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.processInOut(RabbitMQProducer.java:244) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQProducer.process(RabbitMQProducer.java:193) ~[camel-rabbitmq-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:86) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:541) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:506) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:369) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:506) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:264) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:325) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar:2.21.1]
at com.example.admin.backend.api.Partners.create(Partners.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Despite

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.21.1</version>
</dependency>
```

being presnt in pom.xml. My guess is that besides simply registring a data-format, i have to somehow tell Camel to use it, but currently wondering how exactly.

Comment: Add Jackson to TypeConverter? Have a look at [JSON](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) section "Integrating Jackson with Camel's TypeConverters"

Comment: You need to add Jackson annotations to your POJO or it won't know how to parse it into JSON.

Comment: @hk6279 thank you, i'll post solution soon.

Comment: @noMad17 no, i do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hk6279, the problem was solved by adding a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class CamelContextConfig implements CamelContextConfiguration {
    @Override
    public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
        camelContext.getGlobalOptions().put(JacksonConstants.ENABLE_TYPE_CONVERTER, "true");
        camelContext.getGlobalOptions().put(JacksonConstants.TYPE_CONVERTER_TO_POJO, "true");
    }
}
```